# How to use Java for desktop GIS development on Linux system

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, java, linux, development

I need to use Java language for desktop GIS development on Linux system. I need to perform read and write operations on FGDB databases, rasters, and vectors. First, I tried to use GDAL, but GDAL is not very convenient for writing FGDB databases (the FGDB API does not have a Java version). Is there any other better solution?

Comment: You have this tagged with `ArcGIS-Desktop` which isn't available on Linux.  There is a Java ArcObjects, which can run on Linux ArcGIS Server platforms, and can access file geodatabase natively, but you'd be getting on the last stagecoach out of Dodge, technology-wise.